# OLE Object in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am very-very confused how to use OLE Object in Crystal Report

I am performing the following steps :-

(RC - Insert- OLE OBJECT).
Select From File : Select an Image and Place Ole Object to Crystal Report.

But after doing that if you are trying to show preview then nothing will be shown here.

So please describe me what is the problem behind that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example you wana add ole Object to your report 
in c#.net you can do that like this
first you must add references to your project
i usually use CRAXDRT.dll and CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll then you can use the code bellow to add your ole object to your report:

```
CRAXDRT.OleObject to3 = report2.Sections[i].AddPictureObject("YourPictureName.bmp", 0, 0);
to3.Height = 1600;  //just a number as height
to3.Width = 1250;   //just a number as width
to3.Left = 0;       //the left part of the object will be start from the value which you set for this property
to3.Top = 0;        //the top part of the object will be start from the value which you set for this property
```